# C# Singleton UI Threading Issue

Tags: c#, observablecollection, multithreading

I am using a service that someone else has written that gets market data. It connects to their server and you send it a symbol and it sends back data. Well I am trying to use it to have multiple Views open so you can get market data for more than one symbol. The way this is done is that my ViewModel subscribes to the singleton event IncomingMessage and if the message contains the ViewModel's symbol it puts it into an ObservableCollection. And that's where the problem is.

How can I add the message from the event to my collection safely?

[Edit]
I believe the exception is being thrown because my ObservableCollection is bound to a DataGrid on my view.

Comment: You're referring to Views and ViewModels in what technology? ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Wouldn't the lock keyword be of help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: MVVM with WPF.  I think it's because of Binding the ObservableCollection to my view

Comment: You're not really giving us enough information, but probably you are trying to update the UI from another thread which is not allowed.  You could use a DispatcherTimer to dequeue the message from a message Queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to marshal the call to the Add method to the UI thread.  In Prism this is usually done with the event aggregator, but if you are not using prism:

Assuming you have some type `Tick` that represents your market data, and that the data event is just a `System.Action<Tick>`:

```
dataSource.IncomingMessage += (tick) => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<Tick>(AddTheTick), tick);
```

or, simply

```
dataSource.IncomingMessage += (tick) => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<Tick>(myObservableCollection.Add), tick);
```

Comment: I am getting the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Delegate, params object[])'" I'm using your top example since I need to do some validation on the data that comes in.

Answer (score 3):

`ObservableCollection<T>` generally can't be updated from background threads.  You need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke()` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to ensure that the data is added on the thread to which the collection belongs.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => myObservableCollection.Add(value)));
```

That's a pretty common task, it's worthwhile to create an extension method to take care of this for you:

```
static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
{
    internal static void InvokeAdd<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> self, T item)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action<T>)self.Add, item);
    }

    internal static void BeginInvokeAdd<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> self, T item)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<T>(self.Add), item);
    }
}
```

That way you can safe a few keystrokes and type this instead:

```
myObservableCollection.InvokeAdd(value);
```